# What was the "bold move" Chrisjen is referring to in The Expanse - Episode "The Big Empty"?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

After the interrogation of the alleged OPA courier, the Belter Heikki Sobong, Chrisjen Avasarala, the United Nations Assistant Undersecretary, is sitting with Errinwright (the Undersecretary) in an auditorium-like room, discussing the situation between Earth and Mars.

At some point, after mentioning the Belter, she says **"Bold move, I'll give him that".**

**Does she actually talk about the Belter at this time? And what is the move in question?** Or is it this about something else altogether.

The scene is about 18 minutes in into the second Episode of the first season.

I have attached a Screenshot of the scene.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present, there is a "cold war" going on. As Errinwright says..

> "A cold war is a bloodless war, mutual distrust and complete co-dependence. No one wants to change that. Least of all Mars."

The quote would seem to reference *whoever* is making the move. It's unlikely to refer to the courier...more likely whoever is pulling the strings behind it all.

Frankly, I heard it as "give them that" but your subtitles and a transcript I found seem to agree with you.

It seems to refer back to the line before,

> "Heaven help us all if Mars and The Belt decide to share a toothbrush"

Which one can infer to mean that if Mars and The Belt *are* co-operating (and perhaps sharing stealth technology) as Chrisjen suspects, it would be a major shift in the political atmosphere currently in place.

A bold (and potentially dangerous) move indeed.

Comment: Your answer would make sense to me, when it read "give them that" only, as you said.

Comment: I watched the scene on Netflix, in German, again and interestingly the text is not very literally translated at all. In the german subtitles she says "Ein kühner Schachzug, das muss ich ihnen lassen". Vocally, she says "Ein wirklich kühner Plan, das muss ich ihnen lassen. Either way, the word "ihnen" ("them" in english) always refers to a group of people (of any count). So, your answer seems quite valid, and the english text may not exactly reflect the story's intention. Strange though.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, given the fact, that the subtitles and translations are not always exactly equal in various parts of the film. This time, I guess, the real words are more likely "them", as can be understood in the English audio track.